# Auto Refresh IMG-Tag without JavaScript? How is this working?

Tags: html, image

I saw some  tags, that kind of "auto refresh" with a countdown.
For ex. https://cdt-timer.stripocdn.email/api/v1/images/7NDsoWkQCYezugl7_pgSDBZPVYYFW2TRZw5dTC7KR6o

It's an image, but autorefreshes without any script on the page?

Can anyone explain how this is working, maybe with an example/github link?

Thank you

Comment: It's just a gif, and gifs support animation.

Comment: The image link you supplied is a gif file. Try reloading after few seconds and it starts the counter again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an animated GIF; it's all in the image.